# Is there a way to set a Raspberry Pi as a mini Server at home?

Tags: web-server, server

I want to use a Raspberry Pi as a server which can be contacted via a domain
to display a homepage or something else.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** How is it possible?

**EDIT2:**

I got a Raspberry Pi and i need to run a website with php via network over a IP.
Later i want to reach this website through a Domain.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Show us your efforts, what you've done so far in that direction and where exactly you're facing the issues (if any). This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: Yes,you can. There are a lot of good tutorials out there. 
Some tips : Install an OS on the SD card. Boot up the Pi. Install the specific server that you want on the OS. Let's say a web server.
Get free domain at "http://www.noip.com". Do some setting changes in your router. Done.

Comment: This should +1 your Linux skills: http://www.instructables.com/id/Ultimate-Pi-Based-Home-Server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install apache2` will install a web server on your Raspberry.

This is just a vanilla http server though, should suffice as long as you don't need anything more than a static website. Setting up your own domain name is a different story.

Comment: For such a small web server project, I would recommend using lighttpd which has a much smaller footprint on disk as well as in memory: `sudo apt-get install lighttpd php5-cgi`. Then run `sudo lighttpd-enable-mod fastcgi ; sudo lighttpd-enable-mod fastcgi-php`

Comment: ok, i am going to try this but how to remove apache2 again? o.O